# Aerofoil Lift curve

Tags: wing

so I’m trying to identify if my aerofoil of choice, 24xx can generate enough lift.

I’ve been trying to find a Clmax against angle of attack curve online but I can’t seem to find one? Anyone know any good websites for this sort of thing?

Also, any recommendations please on what criteria i should be looking for other than t/c and Mach number when selecting my aerofoil please?

CLmax:1.60

Max mach: 0.29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search for "naca 2412 lift" gave this: http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=naca2412-il

They have these curves for probably any NACA airfoil and a ton others - so just type the airfoil name in that little search box at the top ! ;)

Comment: Hi thanks mate! I was trying Java foil but was a little more complicated